# Altair color bar chart by value not presented

Tags: altair, streamlit

Trying to color a bar chart using a condition based on a value that is not presented in the chart.

I got this dataframe:

[image]

I would like to color the bar green if `row.presented_value > row.coloring_value` , else color red.

I saw examples of conditions by [constant values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60331614/how-to-highlight-a-bar-by-datetime-value-with-altair) and by [displayed values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59427304/dynamic-name-in-altair-alt-condition), but couldn't make it work for me.

In the code example below I would like both `foo` and `bar` to be red.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['bar','foo'],
                  'presented_value':[10,20],
                  'coloring_value':[15,25]})

(alt.Chart(df, height=250, width=375).mark_bar()
 .encode(x='name', y=alt.Y('presented_value', axis=alt.Axis(orient='right')),
         color=alt.condition(alt.datum['presented_value'] > df.loc[df.name==alt.datum.x,
                                                        'coloring_value'].values[0],
        alt.value('lightgreen'),alt.value('darkred'))
        )
)
```

[image: Variation 1]

Changing the first value of `coloring_value` to `<10` both bars will be green even though I would expect only `bar` to be green.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['bar','foo'],
                  'presented_value':[10,20],
                  'coloring_value':[5,25]})

(alt.Chart(df, height=250, width=375).mark_bar()
 .encode(x='name', y=alt.Y('presented_value', axis=alt.Axis(orient='right')),
         color=alt.condition(alt.datum['presented_value'] > df.loc[df.name==alt.datum.x,
                                                        'coloring_value'].values[0],
        alt.value('lightgreen'),alt.value('darkred'))))
```

[image: Variation 2]

Still not coloring by the correct values. Any idea on how to get it done?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Condition expressions cannot use pandas constructs; they must map to [vega expressions](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/). Altair provides the `alt.datum` and `alt.expr` object as convenience wrappers for this.

In your case, when you want to compare two values in the row, the best way to do that is to compare them directly:

```
(alt.Chart(df, height=250, width=375).mark_bar()
 .encode(
    x='name',
    y=alt.Y('presented_value', axis=alt.Axis(orient='right')),
    color=alt.condition(
      alt.datum.presented_value > alt.datum.coloring_value,
      alt.value('lightgreen'),
      alt.value('darkred')
    )
  )
)
```

[image]